# Как подключить изображение находящиеся относительно исполнительного файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qss

Я пытаюсь подключить картинку к фону файла:

```
import sys
import os 

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.resize(800, 800)
        
        url_set = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, "image.png")
        print(url_set)
        url_qt = QUrl.fromLocalFile(url_set)                                     # +++
        print(url_qt)
        f1 = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\wid\image.png'
        f2 = 'image.png'
        url = url_set
        url = url_qt
        url = f1
        url = f2
        self.setStyleSheet('''background-image: url({});'''.format(url))
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но проблема в том, что картинку код находит только 
если она находится в `C:\Users\user\image.png`,
вне зависимости от того где находится исполнительный файл.

Я пробовал подключить через `DIR_PATH`, `QUr`l и указав ссылку вручную не помогло.

> Could not parse stylesheet of object Window(0x1edeb514230)

Я бы хотел избежать использование функций `def paintEvent()`, потому-что постоянно создавать новый объект только для того чтобы присвоить ему фон как по мне не практично.

Comment: Если фон будет постоянный, то лучше добавить картинку в ресурсы и обращаться к ней оттуда http://smhfa.blogspot.com/2014/03/qt_26.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        button1 = QPushButton("Button 1")
        button2 = QPushButton("Button 2")
        lay = QHBoxLayout(centralwidget)
        lay.addWidget(button1)
        lay.addWidget(button2)


stylesheet = """
QMainWindow {

/*  можно так
    background-image: url("D:/_Qt/img/cat.jpg"); 
    или так                                             */

    background-image: url("img/cat.jpg"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center;
}
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(490, 370)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> А как я могу применить фон к любому другому widgets кроме QMainWindow?

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.subWidget = QWidget()
        button1 = QPushButton("Button 1", self.subWidget)
        button2 = QPushButton("Button 2", self.subWidget)
        layH = QHBoxLayout(self.subWidget)
        layH.addWidget(button1)
        layH.addWidget(button2)        

        layV = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layV.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layV.addWidget(self.subWidget)


stylesheet = """
.QWidget {

/*  можно так
    background-image: url("D:/_Qt/img/cat.jpg"); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    или так                                             */

    background-image: url("img/cat.jpg"); 
    background-position: center;
}
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(490, 370)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А как я могу применить фон к  любому другому widgets кроме QMainWindow?

Comment: @orlatym я добавил возможный вариант